# Routeconfig overriding WebApi Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I'm working on a Angular app, using ASP.NET WebApi as a backend.

http://localhost:1653/api/feed works fine, if I remove the catch-all route from the RouteConfig.cs.

When I add it back, it catches the api call also.

```
public class FeedController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/feed")]
    public IEnumerable<FeedItem> Get()
    {
        var items = new List<FeedItem>();
        items.Add(new FeedItem("News from the server!"));

        return items;
    }
}
```

But when removed the Angular app crashes on refresh, because the catch-all route is needed to show all of the views.

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{*anything}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Shouldn't the attribute routing take care of this?

Comment: You have `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();` before all routes?

Comment: `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();` should be in your `WebApiConfig`

Comment: config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes() is in the WebApiConfig. But all routes are in the RouteConfig. Do i need a api route in the WebApiConfig (even if i have attribute routing)?

Comment: What version of MVC are you using?

Comment: MVC5 (System.Web.Mvc is 5.2.3.0)

Comment: What url are you calling from angular? edit/nevermind! Just seen your answer

Answer (score 1):

Found it:

```
   protected void Application_Start()
   {
        Container = UnityConfig.InitializeUnity();
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        ...
```

it does not work if RouteConfig comes first. Ok, so there is that :)